# Which way to check if Javascript is available (in .NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, noscript

What's the effective difference between these two ways of checking JS:

- `Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion.Major < 1` in the .NET codebehind
- The `<noscript>` tag?

I inherited a code base where both are being used next to each other, are they not doing the same thing?

Comment: The point of the [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) tag is not to “check” whether JavaScript is available or not. It’s simply for providing alternative content.

Comment: The first method only tell if the browser support JS, but it doesn't tell if the user deactivate JS

Comment: OK, so just having the `<noscript>` should be sufficient then to display a message in case there's no JS support.